# Как заменить стандартную строку на регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, powershell

Фрагмент исходного кода:

```
$StrBuffIn   = Get-ChildItem -Path $InPath -File |
           Get-Content -Raw -Encoding OEM | Select-String ('"ТКФД","РВМК",1'+[Environment]::NewLine)
```

Как его переделать с использованием регулярных выражений? Текущая реализация поломается, если после единицы окажется пробел, один или несколько.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
Select-String -Pattern '"ТКФД","РВМК",1\s*\n'
```

**Подробности**:

- `-Pattern` - ключевое слово, при котором условие поиска задаётся регулярным выражением
- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
- `\n` - символ перевода строки.